# Should I use the MP3 or AAC codec for a .mp4 file?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, h.264, mp4, aac

We have an encoding process in place using **ffmpeg** on Mac OS X. This process will take a source video and a couple files from that: .m3u8 video, .mp4 video and .mp3 audio file.

By default we've used the video from our m3u8 process which is a h264 (via *libx264*) video with AAC (via *libfaac*) audio.

We are mostly using these videos on mobile devices (hence the m3u8 files) but we also use the .mp4 files for Android, Windows Phone, etc. More and more we also need to offer these same videos on the web via either a flash player or HTML5 player.

Therefore, we'd like to have the best audio/video codec combo for all these uses ... where I'm confused is to what is "standard" for a .mp4 file?

If the .mp4 uses the mp3 codec then it plays just fine everywhere but QuickTime, in QuickTime the video plays but there is not audio (works just fine in VLC player tho.)

I've been told it's due to how QuickTime uses file extensions to assume information about the video instead of trying to actually get the codec data from the file? This does make some sense, if we encode the same file but use AAC for the audio codec then it works just fine in QuickTime.

So --- what's the "correct" or "ideal" audio/video codec combo --- is it best and safe to use AAC (i.e. will it work on a broad range of devices) even though it's not a "free" codec?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard yea that's where I'm a little confused --- .mp4, as it was originally created seems to be AAC audio, from Apple. But it sure didn't stay that way.

Comment: these days, either works fine.  aac will probably be slightly better quality for lower bitrates.

Comment: What about M4A?

Comment: @KyleDelaney https://stackoverflow.com/a/9510754/114558

Answer (score 8):

Compatibility issues set aside, you might want to take into account the quality loss induced by transcoding from mp3 to aac. As your original audio is mp3 encoded, you will have a better end result by remuxing the mp3 bitstream instead of transcoding to aac (even if aac is better than mp3 at a given bitrate).

If your workflow requires lowering the bitrate of the original mp3, then my point looses relevance.

Answer (score 4):

`AAC` is preferred because many modern devices such as tablets and mobile phones might have hardware decoders for it which will result in better battery and lower CPU consumption. Same applies to `h264`.

In recent years a growing number of devices have added hardware acceleration for the (HEVC) `H.265` codec, but that's probably about ~half of the mobile market at best so not yet a default.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video - scroll down for a compatibility table. Seems like either MP3 or AAC work well with H.264

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use the AAC codec, as you said, it works on a wider range of devices and it is better for use in HTML5

Comment: At the moment AAC cannot be played in Google Chrome

Comment: This is why we can't have nice things.

Comment: That only took a 3 years, xD