# MoviePy Audio doesn't exist on iPhone

Tags: python, moviepy

I have produced a video using MoviePy and the audio works perfectly fine on PC, but when I try watch it on iPhone it has no audio. I played the uploaded clip on my PC too so it's not the platform where the video is. Also got a friend to listen on iPhone and it also has no audio so not my device. Edit: also tried playing on samsung tablet (android) and it also plays the audio fine.

This is the outputted video files properties:

[image]

This is my code:

```
from moviepy.editor import ImageClip, AudioFileClip, VideoFileClip, CompositeVideoClip

    clips = []  # list of clips to be composited
    current_duration = 0  # how long the total clip is
    
    bg = VideoFileClip("background.MOV", audio=False)  # remove audio from the background
    
    title_audio = AudioFileClip("audio/title.mp3")  # title audio
    title_clip = ImageClip("screenshots/post.png", duration=title_audio.duration).set_audio(title_audio)  # image + audio
    clips.append(title_clip.resize(width=bg.w).set_position("center"))  # append the resized centred clip
    current_duration += title_audio.duration  # increase the duration
    
    # loop through clips 1-5 doing the same thing
    for comment in range(1, 6):
        com_audio = AudioFileClip("audio/voice" + str(comment) + ".mp3")
        com_clip = ImageClip("screenshots/comment" + str(comment) + ".png", duration=com_audio.duration).set_audio(com_audio)
        clips.append(com_clip.set_start(current_duration).resize(width=bg.w).set_position("center"))  # start at current end
        current_duration += com_audio.duration
    
    final = CompositeVideoClip([bg.subclip(0, current_duration)] + clips)  # composite the clips on top of the background
    final.write_videofile("test.mp4", fps=24)  # output the file
```

Comment: You'll need to use `aac` for the audio when rendering an mp4 to be played on an iphone: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60067579/when-i-try-to-export-my-mp4-created-with-moviepy-from-my-pc-to-my-iphone-the-s - add `audio_codec='aac'` to your `write_videofile` call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on this, you produced a video file that's (probably) `h264/mp3`, which isn't a supported format for iPhone - your video file needs to be `h264/aac` to work on iPhones (and probably any Mac device via Quicktime).

This is also an open issue for `moviepy`: https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/1709

You can specify an `audio_codec` when writing your file to make this work:

```
final.write_videofile("test.mp4", fps=24, audio_codec='aac')  # output the file
```